# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute (SQLite)

Tags: django, django-models

## AIM

Once the User enters `search_text` in the `HashtagSearch FormView`, the function `get_tweets()` will get from Twitter the locations associated with that hashtag.

Then, use `get_or_create` to save the `search_text` in the `Hashtag` db. Then, go through the txt file line by line and, assuming the regex requirements have been satisfied, add the line as a `locations` associated with the `search_text` in the db.

As a summary of the workflow:

1. A User enters `search_text` in the `HashtagSearch FormView`,
2. A function is run within `HashtagSearch FormView` that searches Twitter for tweets using the `search_text` as a hashtag ('the applicable tweets'),
3. Searches 'the applicable tweets' for whether the tweeter has a location saved on their profile. If so, save that location to a txt file,
4. Performs regex on the txt file to filter out 'non-genuine' locations,
5. Saves the locations to the `locations` object associated with the `search_text` in the `Hashtag` model.
6. Render **results.html** with the `location` object associated with the `search_text` in the `Hashtag` model.

## ERROR

```
Request Method: POST
Django Version: 2.0
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'locations'
Exception Location: /mnt/project/mapping_twitter/views.py in get_tweets, line 87
Python Executable:  /mnt/data/.python-3.6/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.5
Python Path:    
['/mnt/project',
 '/mnt/data/.python-3.6/lib/python36.zip',
 '/mnt/data/.python-3.6/lib/python3.6',
 '/mnt/data/.python-3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6',
 '/mnt/data/.python-3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

## CODE

**views.py**

```
    def get_tweets(self, form):
        """ Get tweets from the Twitter API and store them to the db """
        consumer_key = '...'
        consumer_secret = '...'
        access_token = '...'
        access_secret = '...'
        t = Twython(
            app_key=consumer_key,
            app_secret=consumer_secret,
            oauth_token=access_token,
            oauth_token_secret=access_secret,
        )

        # set to the text entered by User in Form
        search_filter = self.request.POST.get('search_text')
        # set the filter for hashtag and quantity
        search = t.search(q='#{}'.format(search_filter), count=50)
        tweets = search['statuses']
        f = open('tweet_locations.txt', 'w+')
        for tweet in tweets:
            if tweet['user']['location']:
                tweet_location = tweet['user']['location']
                f.write("{}\n".format(tweet_location))
        f.close()

        data = open('tweet_locations.txt', 'r')
        # Regex out 'unmappable' locations
        valid_ex = re.compile(r'[A-Z][a-z]+, [A-Za-z]+')

        for line in data:
            valid_tweet_location = str(valid_ex.search(line))
            if valid_tweet_location:
                # ISSUE: save the locations_list to the Hashtag model as the locations associated with the search_text entered
                tweet_object = Hashtag.objects.get_or_create(search_text=search_filter)
                # necessary as locations is a M2M object
                tweet_object.locations.create(valid_tweet_location)
        data.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) method returns the tuple `(obj, created)` instead of only the object. This way you can check whether the object is retrieved or created.

Simply unpack the tuple as follows:

```
tweet_object, created = Hashtag.objects.get_or_create(search_text=search_filter)
tweet_object.locations.create(valid_tweet_location)
```

Answer (score 2):

You posted far too much code here - the traceback showed you where the error was happening, you should have just posted the `get_tweets` method.

The error is indeed happening there. This is because a tuple is what is returned by `get_or_create` - that is, it returns the object and a boolean showing if it was a create. Since your don't care about that, you can just assign it to a variable that is ignored:

```
  tweet_object, _ = Hashtag.objects.get_or_create(search_text=search_filter)
```

Comment: I've edited the question above to remove unnecessary code as per advice.